# 1991 Honda Accord - Starts, Runs Fine for 30-40 seconds, dies

Tags: honda, old-cars

The car starts strong, runs at 1500 rpm fine for about 30-40 seconds,
then sputters and dies.  If I gas it in neutral I can get it up to 4000 rpm or so and hold it maybe a minute tops, before it sputters down.  I managed to drive it, but only a block or two.

It's got gas.  I added more, no deal.  It was LOW on gas when last driven without incident.

I just need to get this car to the junkyard.
I drove it three three times in the last two weeks, each time it was fine
on the freeway, on surface streets, wherever.  But they rejected the paperwork for trivial reasons.

Now the paperwork is in line but...
...how can I get it to the junkyard?
It has to run 100 feet on it's own power at the tow yard to count for the Cash to Clunkers program.

Comment: That could be around the time where closed-loop fuel trimming sets in, if it's a fuel injected engine.

Comment: You'll spend more money getting it running than a tow.

Comment: I think  closed loop takes longer than 40 seconds on this car. But it does sound like a fuel supply problem. By the time you put a pressure tester on it, diagnose it and repair I think *GdD has it right. If your stubborn you might try bypassing the fuel filter. Probably won't work, but worth a try if you got the time.

Comment: Is the filter in this car cleanable?
It's not even my damn car: abandoned by a tenant.  16 mile tow.

Comment: Oh, did I mention it has to run 100 feet on it's own power at the tow yard to count for the Cash to Clunkers program.

Comment: If by chance it is a plugged fuel filter, you can just bypass it. No need to clean.

Comment: I had a 92 Accord that had low fuel pressure, the pump was on the way out. Similar symptoms as you describe. Really nicely engineered vehicle and a shame to junk it, but it sounds like it's in bad condition.

Comment: It's in decent condition, but needs serious suspension work.  The reason it is being scrapped is the owner needs money, and the state will pay to take it off the road.

Comment: So is it EFi or carb?